# Is amplified by a "factor of A" correct?

Tags: word-usage

I was reading about electronics and amplification and I wonder if it correct to say

> the signal is amplified by a factor of A

*A* represents a number here.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's correct. In electronics, you'll likely see it expressed in decibels (dB), but either way works:

> The signal was amplified by 3dB.
>
> The signal was amplified by a factor of 2.